# Why it is advisable to wrap BufferReader around InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, io

```
BufferReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Please explain why `InputStreamReader(System.in)` is passed in `BufferReader()`.

Comment: Is it? InputStreamReaders do charset conversion and end up buffering. You should measure.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) answer this very question.

> In general, each read request made of a `Reader` causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a `BufferedReader` around any `Reader` whose `read()` operations may be costly, such as `FileReaders` and `InputStreamReaders`.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
> ```
>
> will buffer the input from the specified file. Without buffering, each invocation of `read()` or `readLine()` could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

Comment: Quote too long for a comment, made CW answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

A data buffer (or just buffer) is a region of a physical memory storage used to temporarily store data while it is being moved from one place to another. Typically, the data is stored in a buffer as it is retrieved from an input device (such as a microphone, file, disk, etc) or just before it is sent to an output device (such as speakers).

Wrapping the reader in BufferedReader increases the program efficiency by reducing the time it takes to read data from external device each time directly. Instead, BufferedReader can read the data from the external device and store the data in buffer for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

The java BufferedReader class provides buffering to your Reader instances.Buffering can speed up I/O quite a bit.